# Stream.Eval vs Stream.generate

Tags: java-stream, fs2

I am a Scala programer. For a specific project i need to revert to pure java.

I have been meaning to learn what could be an equivalent for using fs2 in java.

I found several candidate such as reactor. However i wanted to start basic with java stream.

I am trying to understand what is the fundamental difference between

Fs2 Stream.Eval to execute an IO and java Stream.generate to execute a side effecting function. Is it exactly the same in practice ?

The book **Grokking Functional Programming** in chapter 9 seem to disagree.

> Imperative approaches tend to suffer from one very important flaw:
> they don’t isolate side effects from pure functions. Their APIs tend
> to treat both impure and pure producers as equals.

Where imperative here is stream in imperative language.

What gotcha should i be aware of ? Because to me it sound pretty similar.

Comment: The purpose of `Stream.generate` is to produce values, to be used as stream elements. While stateful generators are possible, it is definitely not the main purpose to produce side effects.

Comment: Nothing stop me from putting a () -> System.prinln() in there in practice, or any other side effecting code in there.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between “*the main purpose*” and “*nothing stops you from doing that*”? Letting aside that `println()` doesn’t produce a value, hence, the compiler *will* stop you from doing that, you can indeed put side effects into `Stream.generate` but have to live with the fact that programming against the intention of an API will lead to problems. For example, there is no guaranty that the side effects line up with the actual Stream operation. Neither the order nor the number of evaluations has to match with the elements used for the final result.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that "For example, there is no guaranty that the side effects line up with the actual Stream operation." This is useful. I do not understand the next sentence tho. Can you please reformulate ?

Comment: It’s possible that the generator function is evaluated more often than the Stream will consume elements. It’s also possible that the Stream consumes elements in a different order. Take for example `AtomicInteger source = new AtomicInteger(); var list = Stream.generate(source::getAndIncrement).parallel().limit(100).toList();` It’s guaranteed that `list.size()` is `100` but not that `source.get()` will be `100` afterwards. The list is not guaranteed to contain ascending numbers and may contain numbers `>99` (but of course, `< source.get()` and no duplicates, causality still exits)

Comment: This question seems like there's no real way to answer, it's more of a discussion topic. Might need to be closed